# how to add scss support for vuejs

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, vue-material

I'm trying to use `vue-material` but in the [documentation](https://vuematerial.io/themes/configuration/), it only says to read on [Pre-Processors](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/configurations/pre-processors.html), I tried everything on the pre-processors page and couldn't fix my error:

The `scss` part is:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  @import "~vue-material/components/MdAnimation/variables";
  @import "~vue-material/theme/engine";

  .md-layout-item {
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    transition: .3s $md-transition-stand-timing;

    &:after {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: block;
      background: md-get-palette-color(purple, 200);
      content: " ";
    }
  }
</style>
```

The error is:

```
Module build failed: 
  @import "~vue-material/components/MdAnimation/variables";
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: ~vue-material/components/MdAnimation/variables.
```

Comment: maybe you forget `dist` folder!? try `@import  "~vue-material/dist/components/MdAnimation/variables.scss"`.  in last version `vue-material` = 1.0.0-beta-7 component **MdAnimation** is absent 
see folder node_modules/vue-material/dist

Comment: yea turned out it had to be `@import "~vue-material/src/components/MdAnimation/variables.scss"`